# Does だけが mean "but only" or "not just"?

Tags: grammar, particle-が

Earlier today I saw this sign:

[image: smokers are inconsiderate losers]

> 煙{けむり}の行方{ゆくえ}。本人{ほんにん}だけが、他人{たにん}事{ごと}だった。

The English is different enough that I think we can mostly ignore it for the purposes of this question. It helpfully conveys the message, but I'm wondering about the grammar of the Japanese, from which the provided English is quite different.

In particular, I'm wondering about the use of `だけが`. `だけ` is "just" or "only", and `が` is "but", so my reading of this is "Other people's problem, but only/just the person themselves." That's not merely **deliberately ungrammatical** English to convey my confusion, it also seems to convey the opposite message than intended. It seems to be saying that the smoke is only just the smoker's problem, no one elses.

From the context and the English provided, I know it's *supposed* to say, "not just the smoker, it's other people's issue as well."

But I just don't see how `だけが` means "not just", instead of "but only."

What am I not understanding about `だけが`?

Comment: The が is a case particle.

Comment: @Chocolate: Thanks for answering, but I'm not one for whom giving something a grammatical name makes me able to use and understand it. I need usage explained, or examples to clarify. :)

Comment: The original text isn't grammatical so I'd read it as 煙の行方--本人だけが「他人事だなIt's not my concern」という気持ちorという状態だった。→煙の行方に関して、本人だけが「他人事だ」と思っていた。/ 煙の行方は(Where the smoke was going)、本人だけにとって(for only the smoker himself)、「他人事」だった(it was 他人事 for him/it was not his concern) while it should be '他人'事 for 'other people=他人'。The word 本人 is contrasted with the word 他人

Comment: @DaveMG: Chocolate means that you have misidentified が. It is not the "but" が, but rather it is the subject particle が.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Ah, and here I thought I was more in the know by *not* assuming it was the subject particle version of `が`. Doh!

Comment: @Chocolate: Wait... what do you mean the original text is not grammatical? I mean I know it's abbreviated, but is it deliberately wrong in some way? (Assuming, of course, that whatever grammatical error there is would be intentional on the part of the advertiser so they could go for some effect.)

Comment: Umm... not that I'm doubting you guys when you say it's the subject `が` and not the `が` that means "but"... but to me the sentence makes even *less* sense if it's not "but". Hopefully someone can provide a full bodied answer, as I don't think I'm going to get this with piecemeal comments. よろしくお願いします！

Comment: This が cannot be a conjunction, because が as a conjunction has to follow a verb or a copula です/だ...

Comment: I meant to say 「本人(だけ)が他人事だ」 is not grammatical because 本人 cannot be the subject for 他人事だ. If you use 他人事だ as a predicate, there should be some other subject than 本人 and it should be 「~~は本人にとって他人事だ」 or something like that. If you use 本人 as a subject, then the predicate should be something like 他人事だと思う or 他人事だと感じる and it should be like「本人だけが~~を他人事だと思った/感じた/考えたetc.」.

Comment: @Chocolate. Your comment should be an answer. I think your explanation is good.

Comment: I just noticed that 他人事 can be read as ひとごと as well as たにんごと. And if you read it ひとごと, the number of morae will be 7-7-7

Comment: @Flaw-san-- Thanks, but right now I'm too 忙しくって…書けない…誰か代わりに書いて…lol...

Comment: "Not just" is actually an inside-out way of putting it.  That's not what it's "supposed" to say, that's what it *means*.  What it's supposed to say is basically what's on the poster: "The smoker is the only one who doesn't care."  So...again, not "not just" (or "not only").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at some example sentences:

> ゲームとネット**だけが**[生きがい]{いきがい}
>
> 自分**だけが**知ってる[秘密]{ひみつ}
>
> [悲しみ]{かなしみ}**だけが**夢をみる

To put it simply, a strong emphasis is put on whatever comes before the だけが to mean "The only thing", "The only person", "The only reason", etc. In other words, translating it as "not just" would be a mistake. It actually means the opposite, for example you could translate the first example as:

> (Video) Games and the internet are my only reason for living. (Assuming the subject is the speaker)

I hope you can see that "not just" doesn't make much sense in the above sentence.
So, based on the above logic, I would translate the sentence in the poster as:

> Where does the smoke go? **Only** the smoker doesn't care.
> (Which I think is a better translation than what's in the poster :))

As an exercise, how would you translate the last sentence? [悲しみ]{かなしみ}だけが夢をみる

Also, I should warn that these ad campaigns are run by JT (Japan Tobacco) because they try to brainwash people into believing that smokers and non-smokers can live in harmony as long as the smokers obey manners, but I digress..

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. I think after reading this, my confusion wasn't just about だけが, but also 他人事. I took it literally "other people's issue", but when you used the term "doesn't care" in your translation, I'm now seeing 他人事 as being a way of describing the "whatever" attitude of the smoker. Thus, a clunky translation that makes sense to me now is "Only the smoker thinks the problem should be left to others to sort out." Would you say that's a reasonable way of interpreting it?

Comment: @DaveMG: Perhaps. However, it could be the case that the smoker doesn't realize that it's a problem at all rather than thinking it's a problem that should be left for others.

Comment: @Jesse: That the smoker is completely without thought for others was my original interpretation, but I'm trying to reconcile that with what the more literal meaning of the term 他人事, which is "other people's problem."

Comment: @Dave M G: Here, 他人事 means the problem of others, as in, not the problem of myself.  Here, it is simply the opposite of "my problem" (that is, denying or not feeling any responsibility), and does not necessarily mean that "I" think others must deal with it.  Think of 他人事 here as just another way of saying 自分に関係ない.

Answer (score 1):

It's just as Jesse Good says, but I'd like to clarify that だけが is だけ **only** + が **subject marker**, expressing that the noun before だけが is the subject of the clause's verb.